# Data Groupings and Bayesian Analysis for a Generative Model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian, data-analysis

I have a simple question that I think will have potentially many solutions, depending on the level of complexity with which one wants to approach it.

I've built a generative model with two variables and have used Bayesian analysis to estimate the parameters. It is a joint distribution $\mathbf{f_{x,s}(\vec{\theta})}$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is continuous, and $\mathbf{s}$ is an unobserved discrete-choice variable. $\mathbf{\vec{\theta}}$ is a vector of parameters.

That all worked fine, and I was able to estimate the model and perform inference as required. But I have now obtained additional data $\mathbf{y}$ to use on this model , which I have grouped into quantiles to turn into a discrete variable. So say
$\mathbf{y \in \{ y_{1},y_{1},y_{1},y_{1},y_{1} \}}$.

The question is, if I re-estimate the model by the different groupings of $y$, is this equivalent to estimating $\mathbf{f_{x,s|y}}$ ?

Is this a good place to start, i.e—simply grouping the data and re-estimating the model ? Would you use a Bayesian hierarchical model ? Bayesian ANOVA ?

This is my first Bayesian model and would love to get some clues on how to approach inference when one is able to group the data into categories, **after the model has already been specified**.

I understand that the more admissible route would be to re-specify the model using $\mathbf{y}$, and estimate $\mathbf{f_{x,y,s}}$. But is this absolutely necessary ?

To ground the example, suppose $\mathbf{s}$ is abinary choice vairable (*to buy not to buy*), $\mathbf{x}$ is the price of an asset, and $\mathbf{y}$ is a demographic category like income or age.